# Spring Listener Container with Transaction Manager and Retry Advice Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-amqp

I was trying to understand how the Spring Listener Container handles the transactions within a retry context.

I configured something like this:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                           transaction-manager="chainedTransactionManager" 
                           channel-transacted="true" 
                           advice-chain="retryAdvice">
    <rabbit:listener ref="myMessageProcessor" queue-names="test.messages" method="handleMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

And I was hoping that the transaction would be contained within the retry, such that if my transaction fails for any reason, I can decide to retry for specific exceptions and for others just send the message to my DLQ.

However, I was surprised to notice that the retry code is contained within the transaction code and not the other way around, which seemed more sensible.

In other words, Spring listener seems to do:

```
doIntransaction -> doWithRetry -> invokeMyCode
```

I was hoping it would be like this:

```
doWithRetry - doIntransaction -> invokeMyCode
```

My plan was to use a `ChainedTransactionManager` containing both a `JpaTransactionManager` and a `RabbitTransactionManager` here to handle both, the acknowledgement of the messages I read, and the commit of the messages I sent during this transaction and retry my entire transaction depending on certain conditions, but this does not seem to work that way.

Not only that, but after an exception occurs within a transaction, the context might become useless. I need a new transaction for the retry to make sense.

And there is the problem that any exceptions happening during the commit/rollback phase won't be retried, because they occur outside the retry context. I assume they're only retried depending on the `ErrorHandler` configuration, and not based on my advised code. Unforunately the `ErrorHandler` does not have a back off policy or the useful `RetryContext` details counting the number of times I have retried a transaction.

What would be the right or most recommended way to configure a listener witha  transaction manager and retry functionality like in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to achieve your desired behavior by removing the transaction manager from the container and adding a normal Spring `TransactionInterceptor` to the advice chain (after the retry advice).

When the container has the transaction manager, you are telling it to start the transaction before invoking the listener (which is wrapped in the advice chain).

However, you might get some noise in the log because the container will probably still try to ack/commit the delivery because it "thinks" it's using local transactions (where the interceptor would have already done it, if it has the `RabbitTransactionManager` configured).

As long as you don't include the `RabbitTransactionManager` in the `chainedTransactionManager` this won't happen though; the container will simply use a local transaction.

If you include the RTM, you might need to use manual acks or add a dummy transaction manager to the container to prevent that.

Let us know how you make out; I can take a look tomorrow.

**EDIT**

As discussed below, using stateful retry is a simpler solution since the message is rejected and redelivered. But, you need a `messageId` header (or a custom key generator).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Gary. I haven't tried your idea yet, because I came up with another idea that I seem to like a little bit better. Can you take a look at my own answer and see if that would make any sense to you? I'd appreciate any advise if you think this can be problematic. I've been reading Spring AMQP code the whole day trying to find a workaround my problem.

Comment: Yes; that will work - although you don't need the RabbitTM in the container, it can just use a locally transacted channel - we still bind the channel (by default) for downstream use by the `RabbitTemplate`. I see your point about multiple sends being committed (if a retry is successful). You could avoid the explicit transaction template stuff by invoking a `@Transactional` bean to do the JPA stuff and then doing the send, all within the `@RabbitListener`.

Comment: Hey Gary, on second thoughts, I think that if I use a stateful retry the whole transaction is always restarted and solves my problem. I think that's probably much easier. So a channelTransacted in the listener and a retryAdvice that uses a stateful retry should do the trick.

Comment: True, as long as you have a `messageId` property, or a custom `MessageKeyGenerator` that can provide a unique key for each message.

Comment: All our messages are event objects with their corresponding id fields that are unique. However to avoid deserializing it I was considering using a key generator like  `message -> UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(message.getBody())`. The UUID method calculates a MD5 hash from the body bytes and from it a UUID. So every time I should get the same value and we'd be safe. I hope that makes sense. I'm evaluating it now.

Comment: Should be ok, if you can't change the publisher to populate the `messageId` header.

Comment: On yeah, that's a great idea. I will use our publisher side to populate  the message id automatically. That ought to work too.

Comment: If you might have an occasional old message, we also have the `MissingMessageIdAdvice` which allows exactly 1 retry, regardless of the retry interceptor settings. It has been removed from the upcoming 2.0 release because the framework inherently now provides that functionality.

Comment: One caveat of stateful retry here is that if it involves JPA transaction, any exceptions are deferred until commit phase, which happens outside the retry context and therefore there is no way to define a retry policy that e.g. sends the message to a DLQ if we see a database `DuplicateKeyException` or `ConstraintViolationException`. When those happpen, the retry loop is done. I suppose there is no easy way around it with JPA transactions.